# New repository for SVN on new server how to reconnect from TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have recently (successfully) relocated my SVN server from one server to another server using `svnadmin` dump/load.

How do I now reconnect my working directory/folders to the new server?  Do I need to just remove my working folders and fetch it again?  I had checked in everything before hand so there is nothing uncommitted?

This is a windows setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you just need to `relocate` your working copy. Therefore you need to run the command `svn relocate <NewUrl>`. There are some good examples in the SVN documentation [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html) and the TortoiseSVN documentation [here](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html).

If the new repository has a different UUID then your old repository, you need to [create a new working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.initial.html). To change the UUID of your repository, you can use the `svnadmin setuuid` command. See [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.setuuid.html).

Comment: Thank you...I did find it eventually :)